# How do I correctly import Material Design Iconic Font in Polymer 2?

Tags: css, import, icons, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to use the [Material Design Iconic Font](http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/examples.html) in a Polymer 2 project.

But I saw that the CSS import is not working properly (or is it expected?) on Polymer 2.

I imported the `min.css` icons with:

`<link rel="import" type="css" href="./styles/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">`

The only valid way using Polymer 2, but after that only small squares are visible instead of the icons.

I forked the starter kit with enough changes to show you the issue here
https://github.com/robertop87/polymer-typescript-starter-kit-1

What do you think? any idea?

Comment: can you check using this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
` probably browser is blocking CORS.

Comment: Have you tried using `iron-icons` instead, or is there something from this particular font you need? https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-icons/demo/demo/index.html

Comment: @Prajwal <link rel="stylesheet" is deprecated and not working anymore, at least with Polymer 2

Comment: @codeMonkey yep I had to use some of them, but at the end I have to create my own svg icons to use in my project, finally the styles were not be imported correctly.
I think this issue probably will be reproducible with many others "older" css stylesheet.